# Make all Files Available on Local HDD too

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

My customer's using O365 want their documents (DOC/XLS/TXT) to be compressed and backed up to their Local backup machine. For this I need all the files to be available on the Local HDD. There is option of 'Make all Files Available' in Onedrive Settings but this is Manual selection. Can I do the same selection programmatically via Microsoft Graph API or some registry settings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this feature is not available on the Graph API. You can do a feature request for it on the [Graph Uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?category_id=359590&query=Make%20all%20Files%20Available) so that it may be implemented in future.

You can try to [track the contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) of the drive using Graph as a way to sync and see if it can work for you.

Comment: Below link sounds like it does the job ?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview

Comment: I think it should because even the docs for syncing files documents using the delta api  for that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Thanks!! It does say that ,    Note: If you are trying to maintain a full local representation of the items in a folder or a drive, you must use delta for the initial enumeration. Other approaches, such as paging through the children collection of a folder, are not guaranteed to return every single item if any writes take place during the enumeration. Using delta is the only way to guarantee that you've read all of the data you need to.